# WebClient DownloadFile is in use by another process

Tags: c#, webclient

so I am getting an error that my file is in use by another process. I believe this is because it hasn't completely finished downloading before it enters the using statement?

Below is my code, I have tried turning my download into async and using a downloadcompletedevent but that still produces the same problem. It was also suggested to use the dispose function to make sure it releases the file, but that also doesn't seem to help. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
if (file.path.Contains(".zip"))
{
    WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
    Console.WriteLine("http://directory.com/api/download" + file.path);
    string downloadLink = "http://directory.com/api/download" + file.path;
    downloader.DownloadFile(new Uri(downloadLink), "temp.ldif");
    downloader.Dispose();
    using (LdifEntryReader ldif = new LdifEntryReader(new LdifReader("temp.ldif")))
    {
        for (Entry entry = ldif.ReadEntry(); entry != null; entry = ldif.ReadEntry())
            Console.WriteLine("Found: {0}", entry.DistinguishedName);
    }
}
```

**Update:**
Under some recommendations and tried the following:

```
using (WebClient downloader = new WebClient())
{
    Console.WriteLine("http://directory.com/api/download" + file.path);
    string downloadLink = "http://directory.com/api/download" + file.path;
    downloader.DownloadFile(new Uri(downloadLink), @"temp.ldif");
}
using (LdifEntryReader ldif = new LdifEntryReader(new LdifReader("temp.ldif")))
{
    for (Entry entry = ldif.ReadEntry(); entry != null; entry = ldif.ReadEntry())
        Console.WriteLine("Found: {0}", entry.DistinguishedName);
}
```

Comment: You're not disposing of `downloader` safely. Why aren't just using using? This might leave a file handle dangling in case of an exception.

Comment: Do you get that error every time you try to execute this? What happens if you download the file manually and then try to read it using the code shown? Does the `LdifReader` and `LdifEntryReader` work correctly? Also, remove the `Dispose` call and the `Thread.Sleep` from your second example. Neither is required.

Comment: @JimMischel, If I download the ldif manually, it does not cause an exception (it doesn't print anything actually). But at least not an error.

Comment: What line is throwing the exception? The code you show certainly can't throw that exception if it's executing in isolation, unless there's a problem in your reader. If you execute the download and the read *and nothing else before or after*, do you still get the error? I suspect that it works fine the first time, but your reader isn't correctly closing the file, which causes the download to fail the second time around. But that's just a suspicion based on the behavior your describe and without knowledge of the larger context in which the code is executing.

Comment: Hi Jim, the line using (LdifEntryReader, is causing the exception to be thrown. If I execute the download and read I still get that exception when it goes to read it using LdifEntryReader. In a larger context, it runs that section of code (download and read) in a loop for each file in my list.